# MySQL n-part Query for 1-n Relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js

(Just started learning SQL a few days ago so sorry if this is a stupid question!)

I have three tables, Users, Addresses, and AddressCategories. Each User has multiple Addresses, but no more than 1 Address per AddressCategory. I would like to make a single query that searches for Users based on different criteria for each AddressCategory.

Table structure looks like:

Users:

```
id
1
2
```

AddressCategories:

```
category
HomeAddress
WorkAddress
```

Addresses:

```
userId   category     address
1        HomeAddress  1 Washington Street
1        WorkAddress  53 Elm Avenue
2        HomeAddress  7 Bernard Street
```

Let's say I want to search for all users whose home address contains the word "Street" and work address contains the word "Avenue". I can use the query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Users 
INNER JOIN Addresses a1 ON Users.id=a1.userId
INNER JOIN Addresses a2 ON Users.id=a2.userId
WHERE a1.category='HomeAddress' AND a1.address LIKE '%Street%'
AND a2.category='WorkAddress' AND a2.address LIKE '%Avenue%'
```

If I want to query across an arbitrary number of AddressCategories, I can dynamically build a query using the same principle above:

```
// dictionary of query parts
var q_parts = {HomeAddress: 'Street',
                WorkAddress: 'Avenue'
                ...}

// build the query string piece by piece
let q_str1="", q_str2="";
let i=0;
for (q in q_parts) {
    i++;
    q_str1 += "INNER JOIN Addresses a${i} ON Users.id=a${1}.userId ";
    q_str2 += (i==1) ? "WHERE " : "AND ";
    q_str2 += "a${i}.category='${q}' AND a${i}.address LIKE '%${q_parts[q]}%' ";
}

// complete query string
let q_str = "SELECT * FROM Users "+q_str1+q_str2;
```

The way I'm doing it now works, but it's easy to make a mistake building the query string and the final string quickly becomes enormous as the number of categories grows. Seems like there must be a better way. What is the right way to perform such queries in MySQL? (Or is there a problem with how I've organized my tables?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one for query building.
Official site: https://knexjs.org/
Npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex

A sample SQL for don't have to join many times. It is not tested, and just an idea.
You can use `When/then` in `Where clause` for verifying case by case. And finally, filter base on the total categories of a User (group by).

```
SELECT *
FROM
Users Inner Join
  (SELECT userId,
          count(category) AS categoryCount
   WHERE address LIKE '%Street%' LIKE CASE
                                          WHEN category = 'HomeAddress' THEN '%Street%'
                                          WHEN category = 'WorkAddress' THEN '%Avenue%'
                                      END
   GROUP BY userId) a ON Users.id = a.userId 
WHERE categoryCount = ? -- inject your count of all categories here, maybe get from another query
```